# Canvas object not changing X position?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm trying to change the X position of an object by 1 on every `draw()`. However, the ellipse is not moving, and I'm not getting any errors.

```js
function setup() {
    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight - 4);
}

function windowResized() {
    resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight - 4);
}

function draw() {
    background(51, 51, 51);

    var el1 = {
        x: 100,
        y: 100,
        width: 50,
        height: 50
    };

    var el2 = {
        x: 300,
        y: 300,
        width: 50,
        height: 50
    };

    ellipse(el1.x, el1.y, el1.width, el1.height);
    ellipse(el2.x, el2.y, el2.width, el2.height);
    el1.x = el1.x + 1;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.2/p5.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're recreating the `el1` and `el2` variables every frame, so you're restarting them at their default values.

If you want to modify a single `el1` variable, then you need to declare it at the top of your sketch.

Compare this code:

```
function draw(){
  var x = 42;
  console.log(x); // always prints 42
  x = x + 1;
}
```

To this code:

```
var x = 42;

function draw(){
  console.log(x);
  x = x + 1;
}
```